# Why doesn't array.sort work on an array created from a string in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

If I manually create an array with

```
array = ["2","1","3"]
```

array.sort will return a sorted version of the array.

But if I create an array by using

```
array2 = ["213".split(//)]
```

or

```
array2 = []
array2 << "213".split(//)
```

array2.sort will return the unsorted array.

Why doesn't this work? Are the arrays created like that somehow different, and if yes, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You define array2 as ["213".split(//)]. This puts an array (["2","1","3"]) inside an array.  The output is:

> > array = ["213".split(//)]
> >         => [["2", "1", "3"]]

When you try and sort that, it sorts the "bigger" array: the one with one element!
This works, though:

> > array = "213".split(//)
> >         => ["2", "1", "3"]
> >     array.sort
> >         => ["1", "2", "3"]

Answer (score 4):

The expression `"213".split(//)` already returns an array, so in both cases you're actually creating an array and adding that entire thing as the first element in a new array.

```
["213".split(//)]                                                    
=> [["2", "1", "3"]]

array2 << "213".split(//)                                            
=> [["2", "1", "3"]]
```

Notice the double brackets. Sorting this array has no effect, because it contains just one element (itself an array). You want to remove the surrounding brackets:

```
"213".split(//)                                                      
=> ["2", "1", "3"]
```

Answer (score 2):

This bit of code:

```
array2 = ["213".split(//)]
```

is creating an array with one element that is an array.  To sort the array that you are interested in:

```
array2[0].sort
```

But, more likely, you should remove the outer brackets to avoid creating the array of arrays.  The same applies to this:

```
array2 = []
array2 << "213".split(//)
```

It creates an empty array and then adds an array element which happens to be another array.

Answer (score 1):

In the first case, you're creating an array whose elements are "2", "1", and "3".  In the second case, you're creating an array that contains an array whose elements are "2", "1", and "3":

```
ruby-1.8.7-p334 :003 > array = ["2","1","3"]
 => ["2", "1", "3"]    # Notice that this is an array of three elements
ruby-1.8.7-p334 :001 > array2 = ["213".split(//)]
 => [["2", "1", "3"]]  #...but this is an array of an array of three elements
ruby-1.8.7-p334 :005 > array2 = "213".split(//)
 => ["2", "1", "3"]    # Remove those extra brackets and it's equivalent to the first case.
```

If you're read this far, you probably figured out that in the second case, you were just sorting a single-element array and seeing that single element, which was unchanged.